# How can I ignore blank cells while concatenating in Excel with added text?

Tags: excel, email, concatenation, contacts

So I have a Concatenate formula where I take two columns and combine them with text.

**=CONCATENATE(B3,".",C3,"@company.com")**

It takes my contacts first and last name and generates emails.

**Example:**

B3: John 
 C3: Smith

Output: John.Smith@company.com

My issue is it will leave "**@company.com**" in rows with blank cells.

I don't want that. Please help

Answer (score 1):

If you have **Excel 2016** or newer, I'd suggest using the [`TEXTJOIN` Function](https://support.office.com/article/textjoin-function-357b449a-ec91-49d0-80c3-0e8fc845691c) instead of [`CONCAT`](https://support.office.com/article/concat-function-9b1a9a3f-94ff-41af-9736-694cbd6b4ca2), since `TEXTJOIN` has an option to ***Ignore Blanks***.

With **previous versions** of Excel, you could build your own version as a custom function, such as this one:

```
Function TxtJoin(delim As String, ignoreEmpty As Boolean, rg As Range) As String
    Dim c As Range
    For Each c In rg
        If Not ignoreEmpty Or Not IsEmpty(c) Then TxtJoin = TxtJoin & delim & c
    Next c
    If TxtJoin <> "" Then TxtJoin = Mid(TxtJoin, Len(delim) + 1)
End Function
```

This is from another answer of mine [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50741445/8112776).

There's also a similar Q&A [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45843881/8112776).

Answer (score 0):

suggest you use simple If with the use of cencatenate. i used AND also because i thought both b3 and c3 needs to be empty, try it out.
if only another one is empty it will do the formula

```
=IF(AND(B3="",C3=""),"",CONCATENATE(B3,".",C3,"@company.com"))
```

like so
    [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ewwtx.png)